# Frequencies of number in a list - Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have this code that outputs a list of values:

```
ARDD.map(function_B) \
            .filter(lambda x: x is not None) \
            .take(6)
```

Output:

```
['2','10','2','12','3','3']
```

How can I change the code to get this output?

```
[2:2, 3:2, 10:1, 12:1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `reduceByKey` RDD methods:

```py
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['2', '10', '2', '12', '3', '3'])

rdd1 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b) \
    .map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}:{x[1]}")

print(rdd1.collect())
#['10:1', '12:1', '3:2', '2:2']
```